# Should I donate Interaction if action is performed from Siri shortcut?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

If an action is called from the app it should be [donated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts) every time a user calls it. That's clear and simple.

But should it be donated if user called the same action from Siri/shortcuts?

Comment: I don't understand the word "donated" in your question. I suspect it's a translation problem.

Comment: @DuncanC [Shortcut donation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts) is an actual concept documented by Apple, and is relevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @MikeMertsock. I've added a link in my question now.

Comment: Oh, ok.Thanks for the info, @MikeMertsock and Jaroslav. I learned something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have apps that donate shortcuts for actions invoked via Siri/Shortcuts and they perform correctly and pass App Store review.

While it doesn't explicitly address your specific question, the [Donating Shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts) documentation page has this passage that I believe implies that it is correct to donate shortcuts in this case:

> Donate a shortcut each time the user performs the action in your app. Make one, and only one, donation per action at the time the user performs the action. If the user performs the same action again, make another donation.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not.
Here's what I found in the documentation.

> Donate interactions only when the user initiates an interaction in your app. SiriKit already knows about interactions that it sends your app for intent handling.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/ininteraction

Think this way. When your app handles an intent from Siri or Shortcuts,
the system automatically creates an `INInteraction` object that
includes the intent and your response.
So why would the system expect your app to donate an object created by itself?

Only donate `INInteraction` objects originally created in your app.